# Erro ao exibir array em PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, array

Tenho este array em PHP e devo exibir o campo nome e email dos usuarios. 
Porém o php exibir uma mensagem de erro:

```
array(4) 
    { 
        [0]=> object(stdClass)#25 (5) 
            { 
                ["idusuario"]=> string(1) "2" 
                ["nome"]=> string(5) "admin" 
                ["email"]=> string(15) "admin@gmail.com" 
                ["senha"]=> string(3) "123" 
                ["status"]=> string(1) "1" 
            } 
        [1]=> object(stdClass)#26 (5) 
            { 
                ["idusuario"]=> string(1) "3" 
                ["nome"]=> string(5) "teste" 
                ["email"]=> string(15) "teste@gmail.com" 
                ["senha"]=> string(3) "123" 
                ["status"]=> string(1) "0" 
            } 
    }
```

**codigo PHP**

```
<?php

   echo $dados["0"]["nome"];
   echo $dados["1"]['email'];
?>
```

**Mensagem de Erro:**

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined index: nome
>
> Filename: home/list.php
>
> Line Number: 20
>
> Backtrace

:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined index: email
>
> Filename: home/list.php
>
> Line Number: 21

Comment: Qual é a mensagem de erro? E como estás a tentar fazer isso?

Comment: E se fizeres `$dados[0]->nome;`? Cada um dos subelementos é um objeto e não um array

Comment: so funcionar desta forma:  echo $dados[0]->nome;

Comment: com faco para exibir no foreach ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É um stdClass Object, faça assim:

Suponhamos que no seu código o array esteja em $dados

```
// printar o campo nome dentro do loop
foreach ($dados as $dado) {
    echo $dado->nome;
}

// printar o campo nome do primeiro item da array
echo $dados[0]->nome;
```

Comment: Como coloco isso no  while($linha = mysql_fetch_assoc($dados)){ echo #linha[0]["nome"];

Comment: quando este codigo dá erro: Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in D

Comment: eu editei e coloquei um exemplo de como colocar isso dentro do while

Comment: So esta funcionado desta forma:  echo $dados[0]->nome;

Comment: editei novamente, agora tem um exemplo dentro de um foreach, substitui o while, tente e me fala.

Comment: funcionou perfeitamente, Porém existe uma linha vazia ao final..

Comment: como elimino a linha vazia do final ??

Comment: para eliminar o último item da array use a função array_pop(), no seu caso, coloque antes do foreach o seguinte: array_pop($dados);

Answer (score 0):

Quando você encontrar este erro:

> Undefined index: email (ou qualquer que seja)

Significa que você está tentando pegar do objeto um indexador que não existe (uma posição que não existe).

Uma boa solução é dar este comando `die(vardump($minha_variavel));`, ele mostrará toda a estrutura da variável ou objeto, então você chega na seguinte solução:

```
echo $dados[0]->nome;
```

Ou, ainda:

```
foreach($dados as $result){
    echo "O resultado é ". $result->nome;
}
```